# Default result for v-data-table search

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` that can be searched using the search prop. I would like to return a default row if no results are found in the search.

For example, if I had a simple table containing rows for "Apples", "Oranges", "Pears" and I then searched for "Peaches", I would like to return the "Apples" row, rather than "No matching records found".

I attempted to implement this using the `no-results` slot, however, there were a couple of issues with this. First, the styling is not the same as a regular row. This is not a huge problem as I imagine this could be overridden. Secondly, usually when a row is clicked I pop a dialog containing more information - this behaviour does not seem to work with the `no-results` slot.

Has anyone had any experience implementing something similar that could help?

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproduction of this issue using codepen?

Comment: The dialog which you are using should be kept outside the datatable component, then  it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a `custom-filter` function which returns the default entry in case no result has been found.

See also: 
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/data-tables/intermediate/custom-filter.vue

Answer (score 0):

Added a custom search as recommended by Simon above.

```
searchWithDefault(value, search, item) {
  return (value != null &&
    search != null &&
    typeof value === 'string') &&
    ((value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) || (value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("peaches") !== -1))
}
```